# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb) TabBarController->TableViews->ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to make my app work, but after pushing into a UIViewController from a UITabBarController it always crashes(only if I add any class for the ViewController)

Here is the crash log:

2015-03-06 21:59:22.198 devDes4[31560:1990488] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
`(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa513d6cc00 V:[UIImageView:0x7fa513d6f090(64)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa513d70310 V:[UIImageView:0x7fa513d6f090]-(8)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa513d6eb80 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa513d703b0 V:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7fa513d6f090]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa513d6eb80 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa513c1f180 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa513d6eb80(79.5)]>"
)`

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-03-06 21:59:24.298 devDes4[31560:1990488] Failed to set (layer.masksToBounds) user defined inspected property on (NSLayoutConstraint): [ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key layer.
2015-03-06 21:59:24.298 devDes4[31560:1990488] Failed to set (layer.cornerRadius) user defined inspected property on (NSLayoutConstraint): [ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key layer.
2015-03-06 21:59:26.694 devDes4[31560:1990488] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
`(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51606bf10 V:[UIImageView:0x7fa51606d8e0(64)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51606e430 V:[UIImageView:0x7fa51606d8e0]-(8)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa51606d610 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa51606e4d0 V:|-(8)-[UIImageView:0x7fa51606d8e0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa51606d610 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fa516259c60 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fa51606d610(79.5)]>"
)`

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
2015-03-06 21:59:37.718 devDes4[31560:1990488] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "pCv-8q-z3l-view-69w-Xq-gJ3" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'
*** First throw call stack:
`(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108639f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001082d2bb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108639e6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000108d08415 -[UITableViewController loadView] + 249
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000108b4b7f9 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000108b4bc8e -[UIViewController view] + 27
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000108b6f507 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 633
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000108b7b3fe -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 386
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000108b7bf47 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 43
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000108cc1509 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 202
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000108a9f973 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 521
    11  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c314de8 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 150
    12  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c309a0e _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    13  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c30987e _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 24
    14  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c27763e _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 242
    15  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c27874a _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 390
    16  QuartzCore                          0x000000010c278db5 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 89
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010856edc7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010856ed20 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108564b53 __CFRunLoopRun + 1123
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000108564486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010bc089f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    22  UIKit                               0x0000000108a26420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    23  devDes4                             0x0000000107d9f103 main + 115
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010abc9145 start + 1
    25  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)`

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to paste all the crash log. The key point is **"reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "pCv-8q-z3l-view-69w-Xq-gJ3" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'"** Maybe you used wrong class of the controller. If you use UIViewController, there is nothing to do. ***However, If you use UITableViewController, you must implement the dataSoure methods:***

1.`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`

2.`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

3.`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

Comment: It crashes, when I'm trying to pass from UITableController to UIViewController (Push) and only if I set the class for the UIViewController

Comment: There is a class for the TableViewController, with these methods, but when I set any class for the ViewController, it crashes when pushing

Comment: Or have you customed class? If you custom controller, you should set your own class's name

Comment: According to the crash reason, just because you have used UITableViewController , but you didn't set it's tableView (or implement the dataSoure methods properly). It's better to paste some related codes!